# Шаблон структуры с произвольным числом полей

Tags: c++, c++11

Возможно ли в C++ создать шаблон структуры с переменным числом полей?
 При этом число и тип полей задавались бы аргументом шаблона типа typename enumName.

Comment: такой шаблон называется `std::tuple`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью массива, если это вам подходит:

```
template<class T,int N>
struct S {
  T arr[N];
} ;

S<char,5> s={{'a','b','c','d','e'}};
S<int,5> i={{1,2,3,4,5}};
```

Comment: а такой шаблон называется `std::array`